# Editing attribute table, when it's not allowing to edit the output field length

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, editing, attribute-joins

I joined two attributes making a field called `"fid"` to appear. Since then when I try to edit or add a field I am unable to change the **output field length** or the **precision**. I have tried deleting the `"fid"` but when I do I get a error. Can somebody explain me why?

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using QGIS

Comment: FID is a primary key for a DBaseIV table, it is mandatory. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649779/changing-dbf-field-size but I suspect that changing the field format is not implemented and/or you've got your table locked. The field length and precision, from memory so I'm not 100% sure, are fixed and it is only the table display properties that are modified, that is your edits to the field display aren't persisted with the DBF, that is the next time you open it the display would revert to the default.